# Does it a fair and straightforward way of measuring the fastest function variation?

Tags: c, optimization

I am trying ways of making faster some parts of a project. The problem is that how to measure which of variations of a function would have the best performance. I am following this idea:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

void func_v1(void) {
    ...
}

void func_v2(void) {
    ...
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    size_t r, i;
    size_t trials_func_v1, trials_func_v2;
    size_t func_v1_score = 0, func_v2_score = 0, ties_score = 0;
    const size_t runnings_nr = SOME_VALUE;
    clock_t start, stop;

    for (r = 0; r < runnings_nr; r++) {
        start = clock();
        stop = clock() + CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        for (i = 0; clock() < stop; i++) {
            func_v1();
        }
        start = clock() - start;
        printf("*** func_v1(): %f ms (%d trials)\n",
               1000 * (double) start / CLOCKS_PER_SEC / i, i);
        trials_func_v1 = i;

        start = clock();
        stop = clock() + CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        for (i = 0; clock() < stop; i++) {
            func_v2();
        }
        start = clock() - start;
        printf("*** func_v2(): %f ms (%d trials)\n",
               1000 * (double) start / CLOCKS_PER_SEC / i, i);
        trials_func_v2 = i;

        if (trials_func_v1 > trials_func_v2) {
            printf("*** func_v1() was faster.\n\n");
            func_v1_score++;
        } else if (trials_func_v2 > trials_func_v1) {
            printf("*** func_v2() was faster.\n\n");
            func_v2_score++;
        } else {
            printf("*** func_v1() and func_v2() have tied.\n\n");
            ties_score++;
        }
    }

    printf("--\n\n[Final result]\n\n");

    if (func_v1_score > func_v2_score) {
        printf("*** func_v1_score have won %d times against %d.\n",
               func_v1_score, func_v2_score);
    } else if (func_v2_score > func_v1_score) {
        printf("*** func_v2_score() have won %d times against %d.\n",
               func_v2_score, func_v1_score);
    } else {
        printf("*** func_v1() and func_v2() have tied (%d x %d).\n",
               func_v1_score, func_v2_score);
    }

    printf("*** Ties total: %d times.\n", ties_score);
    printf("*** Runnings total: %d times.\n", runnings_nr);

    return 0;
}
```

Does it way a fair way of measuring which variation is really better? It is being executed in user mode, not in kernel mode with preemption disabled.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should discard the first 100 or so calls to each function from the timings to give the caches time to warm up.

Comment: Also to be pedantic, since the clock resolution is already pretty terrible, you should probably spin on `clock()` until the value changes, and use _that_ as your start time along with `stop = start + CLOCKS_PER_SEC`.

Comment: Why cant you measure the execution of each of the functions separately using time command. In one program, invoke only f1 in a loop, and measure the execution time. In another program, invoke f2 in a loop and measure the execution time. If you are in a *nix machine, you can use the time utility to measure this.